# Avoid to load all javascripts files

Tags: javascript, typescript, asp.net-core, rxjs5

I using rxjs as follow in typescript:

```
import {Observable} from "./rx/Rx"

var main = () => {

  $(".ui.dropdown").dropdown();
  $(".left-half").backstretch(["../images/lotus.jpg"]);

  var source = Observable.range(0, 3);


  var subscription = source.subscribe(
    x => {
      console.log("Next: ${x}");
    },
    err => {
      console.log("Error: ${err}");
    },
    () => {
      console.log("Completed");
    });

};

$(document)
  .ready(() => {
    main();
  });
```

and the files structure

[image]

the problem is, typescript compile it to multi files instead only one file.
[image]

Everythings works fine, but all scripts from rxjs will be load as show:
[image]

To load the page, it takes **25.42s** and that is horrible. I am using only `Observable` object and all libraries will be loaded.

How can I prevent long loading?

**Update**
For backend I am using ASP.NET Core and the tsconfig file looks as follow:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "amd",
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "noEmitOnError": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "../wwwroot/js"
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "wwwroot"
  ]
}
```

And require.js is used(layout template):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>@ViewData["Title"] - IndustryCloud</title>

  <environment names="Development">
    <link href="~/lib/sui/semantic.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
  </environment>

  <environment names="Staging,Production">
    <link href="~/lib/sui/semantic.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="~/css/site.css" />
  </environment>

</head>
<body>

  @RenderBody()

  <environment names="Development">
    <script src="~/lib/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/jquery-backstretch/jquery.backstretch.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/sui/semantic.js"></script>
    <script src="~/lib/require/require.js" data-main="../js/signin.js"></script>
  </environment>

  <environment names="Staging,Production">

  </environment>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Minification and bundling will do the job.

Comment: What build system do you use in your project?

Comment: People often solve that issue with AMD loaders. See for example http://requirejs.org/

Comment: I updated my posts, please check.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I prevent long loading

Please use a module bundler to bundle and ship just one JS file e.g. webpack

## More

Here is a blindingly simple (feature poor) quickstart : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/quick/browser.html